# What theme function outputs the administrative overlay in D7?

Tags: 7, theming

What theming function generates the output for the admin overlay in d7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To output the overlay, Drupal uses a template file, [overlay.tpl.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--overlay--overlay.tpl.php/7). To use that template file, the Overlay module implements [hook_page_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_page_alter/7), which contains the following code:

```
  $mode = overlay_get_mode();
  if ($mode == 'child') {
    // Add the overlay wrapper before the html wrapper.
    array_unshift($page['#theme_wrappers'], 'overlay');
  }
```

The Overlay module has also a preprocess function for that template file: [template_preprocess_overlay()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--overlay--overlay.module/function/template_preprocess_overlay/7).